# Detecting if an anchor exists for an entry

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

Im trying to display "No website" if there is not a website link available.  My code is below.  It runs but will not display "No Website".

```
links = page.css("a.track-visit-website")

links.each do |link|
    if links == nil
        puts "no website"

    else
        puts "#{link['href']}"
    end
end
```

New to Nokogiri, what am I doing wrong here.

Here is script if you would like to replicate.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.yellowpages.com/austin-tx/screen-printing?g=Austin%2C+TX&q=screen+printing"))


links = page.css("a.track-visit-website")



links.each do |link|
    if links == nil?
        puts "no website"

    else
        puts "#{link['href']}"
    end
end
```

Comment: `if links == nil` . Shouldn't it be `if link == nil` ?

Comment: either way its not working.  Still testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find an element that represents the result or company. Only from there can you determine if that company has a website or not.

Assuming you only care about the companies listed in the actual search results, the following will iterate through the companies and get their website if available or output no website:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.yellowpages.com/austin-tx/screen-printing?g=Austin%2C+TX&q=screen+printing"))

companies = page.css('#results div.result')
companies.each do |company|
    website_link = company.at_css("a.track-visit-website")
    if website_link
        puts website_link['href']
    else
        puts 'no website'
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you give a sample page so that we can reproduce the same issue?

Comment: I added my full script in the original question so you can replicate.

Comment: I assume that you mean to check if the search results have a website or not. If so, try this updated answer.

Comment: AHA! Very nice.  Thank you for clarifying that!

Answer (score 1):

You are testing the whole of the links array for nil rather than the individual element. Try doing

```
if link.nil?
  puts "No Website"
else
  ....
```

Comment: This doesnt work.  I thought maybe it would, but Im testing for each indivudal link being nil or not.

Comment: @user2908778 Writing `if link == nil?` is very different from writing `if link.nil?`